# how can I add a URL parameter to a link on my website

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

i'm new to this, but I am trying to pass parameters I get from the URL to a link on the webpage.

So I have this URL:

`localhost:8080/testsite/person?name=Tom`

On the page I have a link like this

`<a href="localhost:8080/testsite/viewinfo?person=[ENTER Person name here.]>View info</a>`

and I want to insert the value in the `person` parameter to the `[ENTER Person name here]`

such that the link is

`<a href="localhost:8080/testsite/viewinfo?person=Tom>View info</a>`

How can I do this?

Preferably not with Javascript

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_GET_method

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Looking at this URL:
http://localhost:8080/testsite/person?name=Tom

for an example in PHP

```
    if (isset(@$_GET['person'])) {
        $person = @$_GET['person']; 
    }
```

This will create a variable named $person that will be equal to "Tom"

Please sanitize what you GET though, because just accepting whatever a user inputs will leave you open to problems (i.e. sql injection).

Answer (score 0):

$_GET contains the keys / values that are passed to your script in the **URL**.
If you have the following URL :

```
http://www.example.com/test.php?a=15&b=umar
```

Then $_GET will contain :

```
array
  'a' => string '15' (length=2)
  'b' => string 'umar' (length=4)
```

Of course, as $_GET is not read-only, you could also set some values from your PHP code, if needed :

$_GET['my_value'] = 'test';

But this doesn't seem like good practice, as $_GET is supposed to contain data from the URL requested by the client.